# Show that if $X$ has the discrete topology, then $X$ is totally disconnected. Does the converse hold?

Tags: general-topology

> A space is totally disconnected if its only connected subspaces are one-point
>   sets. Show that if $X$ has the discrete topology, then $X$ is totally disconnected.
>   Does the converse hold?

my attempts : i know that Totally disconnected means that no two points are in the same connected component. So for $x,y\in X$ there is no connected set containing both points. In particular the set $\{x,y\}$ is not connected, thus is discrete..

As  i can not able to prove this

Pliz  help me

Comment: Think about the rational numbers with the usual topology. What are the connected sets? Is the topology discrete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a counterexample, consider the set
$$
X = \{1/n : n = 1,2,3,\dots\} \cup \{0\} \subset \Bbb R
$$ 
Verify that $X$ is totally disconnected, but is not discrete since the subset $\{0\}$ fails to be open.

Comment: thanks  alots @omnomnomnom

Comment: @Ben Grossmaan    In discrete space all set are both open and closed . Here  im not getting  why $\{0\}$  fail to  be open  ?

Comment: @jasmine The point is that even though $X$ is totally disconnected, the topology on $X$ is **not** the induced topology, which is how it can hold that $\{0\}$ is not open

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment: the topology on $X$ is not the **discrete** topology

Answer (score 3):

A set $X$ is totally disconnected if the only connected subsets $S \subset X$ are point sets. Note that points are open in the discrete topology, which means that if $S \subset X$ contains two or more points, you can write $S$ as the union of its points, which are open and obviously disjoint $\rightarrow S$ will be disconnected. This means the only connected components will be points $\rightarrow X$ is totally disconnected.

Comment: thanks@Yagger...